# Webform and Jquery Validate Plug-In - Submit button is being disabled

Tags: javascript, webforms

Having an odd issue using Webform and the Jquery Validate plugin.

I have a custom page where I added the following lines to the template under the  tag:

```
    <!--   Core JS Files   -->
    <script src="/sites/all/themes/tao/assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Jquery Validate -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
$("#webform-client-form-45").validate();
</script>
```

The form does validate but if there is an error the submit button is disabled:

```
<input class="webform-submit button-primary  form-submit hide-submit-disable" type="submit" name="op" value="Submit" disabled="">
```

I cannot find where / why this is happening. If I do not use the validate plug-in then all works fine but my hope is to be able to use the plug-in.

Anyone else have an experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [Clientside Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) and it just automatically handles everything. I have not tested it with the latest Webform 8.x-5.x beta release.

There is also a [screencast](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-improve-webform-client-side-validation-video) showing how the Clientside Validation module works with the Webform module for Drupal 8.